# Change FeignClient url at runtime

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

Having Feign client as presented:

```
@FeignClient(name = "storeClient", url = "${feign.url}")
public interface StoreClient {
    //..
}
```

Is is possible to make use of Spring Cloud capabilities of environment changes to change the Feign url at runtime? (Changing the `feign.url` property and invoking `/refresh` endpoint)

Answer (score 3):

As a possible solution - `RequestInterceptor` could be introduced in order to set URL in `RequestTemplate` from a property defined in the `RefreshScope`.

To implement this approach you should do the following:

1. Define `ConfigurationProperties` `Component` in the `RefreshScope`

   ```
   @Component
   @RefreshScope
   @ConfigurationProperties("storeclient")
   public class StoreClientProperties {
       private String url;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Specify default URL for the client in the `application.yml`

   ```
   storeclient
       url: https://someurl
   ```
3. Define `RequestInterceptor` that will switch URL

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class StoreClientConfiguration {

       @Autowired
       private StoreClientProperties storeClientProperties;

       @Bean
       public RequestInterceptor urlInterceptor() {
           return template -> template.insert(0, storeClientProperties.getUrl());
       }

   }
   ```
4. Use some placeholder in your `FeignClient` definition for the URL, because it will not be used

   ```
   @FeignClient(name = "storeClient", url = "NOT_USED")
   public interface StoreClient {
       //..
   }
   ```

Now `storeclient.url` can be refreshed and the URL defined will be used in `RequestTemplate` to sent http request.

Answer (score 1):

A bit extended answer with `RequestInterceptor`:

1. `application.yml`

```
app:
  api-url: http://external.system/messages
  callback-url: http://localhost:8085/callback
```

2. `@ConfigurationProperties`

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class AppProperties {
    private String apiUrl;
    private String callbackUrl;
    ...
}
```

3. `@FeignClient`-s configuration

Make sure your `...ClientConfig` class is not annotated with any `@Component`/... annotations or is found by a component scan.

```
public class ApiClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor(AppProperties appProperties) {
        return requestTemplate -> requestTemplate.target(appProperties.getApiUrl());
    }
}
```

```
public class CallbackClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor(AppProperties appProperties) {
        return requestTemplate -> requestTemplate.target(appProperties.getCallbackUrl());
    }
}
```

4. `@FeignClient`-s

```
@FeignClient(name = "apiClient", url = "NOT_USED", configuration = ApiClientConfig.class)
public interface ApiClient {
    ...
}
```

```
@FeignClient(name = "callbackClient", url = "NOT_USED", configuration = CallbackClientConfig.class)
public interface CallbackClient {
    ...
}
```